# AJAX: how to post empty arrays?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

i have an associative array with lists. Take a look at the following JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(fields);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "sb1":[],
  "sb2":["val1","val2","val3"],
  "sb3":["val1","val2","val3"]
}
```

As you can see, array-entry "sb1" is empty. Array "sb1" disappear while posting var "fields" to PHP.

Here is a code-snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fields = {};
//The following saves selectboxes and options in var fields//
    $("select").each(function() {
      var $select = $(this);
      fields[$select.attr('name')] = $select.find('option').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get();
    });

    var jsonObj = fields;
    var jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(fields);
    console.log("JSON.stringify(fields): " + jsonStringify);
//Result is OK

    $.ajax({
      url: "saveJson.php",
      type: "post",
      data: { jsonStringify : jsonStringify },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("data transmitted: " + response);
//Response doesnt transmit empty arrays!
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If `JSON.stringify` includes everything, jQuery is surely sending everything, as it can't change the string. It's the serverside code you're using that doesn't understand the empty arrays.

Comment: So i should take a look at the PHP-scripts, right?.. Damn, i am little bit stupid..... Thank you! Pls write this as answer, i ll mark it as solution

Comment: I think it's the way PHP interprets forms, empty values are excluded

Comment: Do u know a way to avoid this? I am using `$jsonEncoded = json_encode($_POST["jsonStringify"]);`

Comment: You could use `empty()`, `array_key_exists()` etc. to just check if the key exists before you try to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript code send the empty array. If you want to have the empty array in the response of your request, you have to modify the code of your server.